# warning for syntax error in ExpressionLanguage

Tags: eclipse, el

I'm currently reviewing some points of an old project and I got stucked in a IDE warning.

Warning: Syntax error in EL. (More specifically: error is located in **href**.)
This is the only info eclipse gives me on the warning, whats is kinda upset also.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{resource['img/favicon.ico']}"/>
```

Image works correctly but I still get the warning. Would someone be able to tell me what is wrong with the sintax?

Comment: Why not add EL as a tag instead of java? And sure there is not more about the syntax error in the warning? And is it an ide warning? Sooo much more a developer could (should) add to a question like this.... cheers

Comment: Sorry, first question. kinda new to this thing. I'll edit.

Comment: If it runtime works, ignore the warning... And what is your Eclipse version? 1.0.9?